# How can I remove port number on ssl domains

Tags: ssl, proxy

I serve two ssl domains on different ports using apache2.2.3. My server version is CentOS 5.11. **I can't update the server**.

For example:

- `https://one.domain.com/`
- `https://two.domain.com:444/`

These works properly.

I want to remove port number from address in second domain like `https://two.domain.com/`.

How can I do it with current environment?

Comment: Use SNI https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication

Comment: My server is Centos5.1 and apache 2.2.3. It doesn't support SNI.
So I created 2 ssl domains on other port.

Comment: You'll need to update then. If you can't then you'll need one IP address per domain

Comment: How come you can't upgrade?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've two options:

1. Use a separate IP address for the second server config. Note this could still be hosted on same server if you can configure two IP addresses on your network card or add another network card.
2. The easier option, and to save an IP address, is to use a cert which works for both domains. More details here: [Disabling SNI for specific virtualhost on Apache](https://serverfault.com/questions/720922/disabling-sni-for-specific-virtualhost-on-apache/721019#721019).

But you really should think about upgrading. Those are very old versions that you're on.